# Let $M$ be a $R$-module generated by one element. What do the submodules look like? Are they finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M = Rm_1$. Then I would say if $m' \in M'$ where $M'$ is a submodule, then also $Rm'$ has to be contained in $M'$. But how I see that $M'$ is actually of the form $M' = Rm_2$ for some $m_2 \in M$?

Comment: In general a submodule of a module with one generator may not be generated by a single generator.

Comment: Are you familiar with Noetherian rings?

Comment: Learning right now about them.

Comment: If $M=Rx$, then $M\cong R/\operatorname{Ann}_Rx$. Now, submodules correspond to ideals of $R/\operatorname{Ann}_Rx$ and there is no reason that these are finitely generated, unless that ring is Noetherian (so they are finitely generated by definition or characterization, whichever you like).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to see this is to take $R$ to be a non-Noetherian ring and let $M = R$, which is generated by $1_R$. Since $R$ isn't Noetheriean there is a submodule of $M$ which isn't finitely generated.